# Chrome will only pull emoji's from twemoji.maxcdn.com for todoist

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Recently the agency I work with decided to block the maxcdn.com domain.  That's when all my emoji's for todoist stopped working.  I've tried using a bunch of different emoji extensions for chrome, but regardless of what I use, it uses the twemoji.maxcdn.com source to try to retrieve the image.  Is this something that Todoist is doing or is it Chrome?  I haven't noticed broken emojis on other sites, but I'm wondering if some part of todoist - maybe their react web server or something, uses that domain?  Are their other emoji stores out there that I can somehow insert or is this just a server-side thing that Todoist would have to fix/change in order for it to work for me?

Comment: Justin from MaxCDN here.  Is there a reason the agency blocked `*.maxcdn.com`?  We also fixed an issue today that **might** be part of the problem: https://github.com/twitter/twemoji/issues/140

Comment: Justin, I don't know why it was blocked, but it's a DOD agency and they often block domains for security/malware/etc. issues.  I would ask them about making an exception, but I don't think I can justify emoji's being "mission critical" to my job. :)

Comment: I appreciate the info. That is such a bummer because we heavily monitor any security or malware vulnerabilities on our properties, especially `*.maxcdn.com` since that is our main domain.  If there is anything I can do to ensure this is a false positive please let me know: jdorfman at maxcdn com

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure there's anything you could do other than give me an idea of what else might be effected by this that I could reasonably say is important to my work as a web developer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Twitter's [twemoji](http://twitter.github.io/twemoji/) is one of the most popular tool. It's free, fast and reliable - and provides good quality icons. That's why most of the developers depend upon it.

twemoji uses Maxcdn CDN services. You can contact the developers of that extension, and ask them to use any alternate service.